# How do I install and use Vue.js with Sails JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, vue.js

I've built my website's backend already via Sails JS and now I want to integrate Vue.js in to my project. I've installed Vue and VueResource via npm install --save and I've created an app.js file in my assets/js folder.

However, when I require Vue and VueResource in my app.js file I get these error messages in Chrome:

```
app.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
localhost/:57 Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
```

I'm new to JavaScript so all I can figure out about this is that the Javascript isn't being built or something similar since require is a Node feature. How can I get my server to build the app.js file so that it functions on the client side? I can barely find any information on this via Google that explains it in a way that a beginner can understand and they seem to just skim over the entire installation part.

Comment: Are you using something like Browserify or Webpack to compile the Javascript? The `require` keyword is something Node.js uses and it wouldn't work if run as-is in the browser.

Comment: @MatthewDaly, I just installed sails-webpack and configured the build script and it seems to be working as intended now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing and using Sails-Webpack fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

yes.. there is no `require` global function in browser, you have to include the vuejs manually via `script` tag.

> Simply download and include with a script tag. Vue will be registered
>   as a global variable.

That what the [doc](https://vuejs.org/guide/installation.html) said.

If you really want to use `require` function like you've done on server side,  you can use module loader like `requirejs`

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, `require` is not a native JS function. You need to compile the JS with something like Gulp or Grunt (I'd suggest Gulp). If you want an out of the box solution try https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir as it has a number of pre-built build scripts (one being for Browserify)